# Mendel's experiment

Tags: statistics

Let's consider the classic Mendel's cross fertilisation of peas. 
The numbers of peas of different types are:

(1) wrinkled and green: 37

(2) wrinkled and yellow: 116

(3) round and green: 124

(4) round and yellow: 315.

Let's assume that $p_i$ where $p=1,2,3,4$ is the probablity of one of these 4 options. 
The problem is to test the hypothesis:

$H : (p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)/p_1 = (1, \theta, \theta, 3\theta)$ for some $\theta >0$ with a significance level $\alpha=0,05$.

My solution is:

1. We need to verify hypothesis
   $X \sim \operatorname{Mult}(n, \frac{1}{1+5\theta},\frac{\theta}{1+5\theta},\frac{\theta}{1+5\theta},\frac{3 \theta}{1+5\theta})$.
2. We compute MLE of $\theta$:
   from optimalisation of $L(\theta) = c \cdot (\frac{1}{1+5\theta})^{37} \cdot (\frac{\theta}{1+5\theta})^{240}\cdot (\frac{3\theta}{1+5\theta})^{315}$ we get that
   $\hat \theta = 3$.
3. We can estimate probabilities:
   $p_1 = \frac{1}{16}$,
   $p_2=p_3 = \frac{3}{16}$,
   $p_4 = \frac{9}{16}$
   and obtain the expected numbers of peas in their 4 different types:
   $n_1=37$,
   $n_2=n_3=111$,
   $n_4=333$.
4. We can now use chi-squared test:
   $\chi ^2 = 2,64$.
5. $\chi ^2 = \chi ^2 (4-1-1)=\chi^2 (2)$ and
   $\chi^2_{2, 0,05}=5,991$ therefore we have no reason to resign from null hypothesis.

My only question is if there is any other way of solving this problem. For instance: except MLE, can we estimate $\theta$ in other way? Is it necessary to estimate it? Maybe there is any non-parametric test?

Comment: I am confused : Mendel's claim is that the probabilities are $p_1=\frac{1}{16}$ , $p_2=p_3=\frac{3}{16}$ and $p_4=\frac{9}{16}$, so why not just use a non-parametric chi-suqared test ?

Comment: We don't assume the exact $1:3:3:9$ proportion but the proportion like in null hypothesis for some $\theta$.

Comment: In this case, I think, you have to estimate first

Comment: If you are using $1:3:3:9$ together with the total from the observations then I suspect you have $3$ degrees of freedom.  If you are calculating marginal probabilities from the observations then I think you have $1$ degree of freedom.  You only get $2$ degrees of freedom if you make an estimate of your $\hat \theta$ from the observed data